# Set Azure SQL Server Firewall Off using either ARM or powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-server

I want to set set Azure SQL Server Firewall Off either using ARM or powershell.

One  possible solution is setting the start and end IP to 255.255.255.255 in ARM.
I also tried removing the block from ARM template file which is used to create the firewall rules. But, even that didn't help.

But, I want to know if there is any other way to do it?

Comment: Could you add a rule with start and end IP to 255.255.255.255  via `New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule`?

Comment: @Joy yes. I tried it from ARM template. It does set the firewall setting to OFF but, I looking for an alternative to this.

Answer (score 1):

It was just as simple as it could be. Not sure how i did not see it. Anyways, for those who stuck with the same thing. Here are the options to turn the Firewall Off.

1. In ARM template you can put start and end IP as 255.255.255.255. This will set the firewall to off however it will leave a firewallrule line with name (that you provide in ARM). You can delete it using powershell command Remove-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule.
2. If you're giving start and end IP as 0.0.0.0, it will set the firewall to be on by default. Now use Powershell command Remove-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName "server" -RuleName "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps"

Answer (score 0):

its not 255.255.255.255, its 0.0.0.0 :)

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
    "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
    "type": "firewallRules",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "properties": {
        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: this will set it on. I want the option to be off when the resource is created.

Comment: you cant really remove anything with arm template, well, you can, but you'd have to be pretty clever\cautious depending on what you do. one thing you can try, change the end and start IP address in arm to something random, 1.1.1.1, for example. and change it back to 0.0.0.0 at the end of deployment with another resource (has to be in a nested deployment)

Answer (score 0):

For powershell, details refer to [here](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings-powershell.md):

turn on:

```
New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName 'resourcegroup1' -ServerName 'Contoso' -FirewallRuleName "ContosoFirewallRule" -StartIpAddress '192.168.1.1' -EndIpAddress '192.168.1.10'
```

turn off:

```
Remove-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule –FirewallRuleName 'ContosoFirewallRule' –ServerName 'Contoso' -ResourceGroupName 'xxx'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is to either set or remove the firewall rule. What I want is when I deploy my ARM template, by default the firewall setting should show "Off".